# Selecting xml elements with the same name with simple_load_xml in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a XML (simplified) like this:

```
<article>
    <title>My Article</title>
    <image src="someurl.jpg" />
    <image src="someotherurl.jpg" />
</article>
```

How do I select the `<image>` elements? They have the same name. To select the `<title>` i simply do this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file( "theurltomyxml.xml" );
$article = $xml->article;
$title = $article->title;
```

But how do I get the images? They have the same name! Just writing `$article->image` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :-

```
foreach ($xml->xpath("/article/image") as $img)
{
  ...
}
```

Or (is list of image node, so normal way of access array is workable)

```
$xml->image[0];
$xml->image[1];
```

Comment: The second solution: Yes it works but only if I always know the number of <image> elements. Which I don't. How would I do if the number of elements is unknown?

Comment: Use the first one with a loop

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question/answer but I had a similar issue and solved it by using the second solution by ajreal with a few adjustments of my own. I had a series of top level nodes (the xml was not formatted properly and didn't split the elements into parent nodes - out of my control). So I used a for loop that counts the elements then used ajreal's solution to echo back the contents I wanted with the iteration of $i.

My use was a bit different than above so I've tried to change it to make it more relevant to your images issue.  Anyone please let me know if I made a mistake.

```
$campaigns = $xml->children();

for($i=0;$i<=$campaigns->count();$i++){
    echo $campaigns[$i]->article->title . $campaigns[$i]->article->image[0];
}
```